# g++ undefined reference to 'Curve:Curve()'

Tags: c++, g++

Getting the following errors when I'm compiling with g++:

Parser.cpp:(.text+0x2478): undefined reference to `Curve::Curve()'

Parser.cpp has the following as header:

```
#include "Bezeir.h"
```

In Bezeir.h I have:

```
class Curve {
    public:
        Curve();
};
```

In Bezeir.cpp:

```
#include "Bezeir.h"

Curve::Curve(){
    count = 0;
}
```

I'm getting a couple of the same error for other classes but their cases are more or less redundant. This seemed consistent with what I'd read for .h/.cpp file, so I'm a tad confused.

Comment: How are you calling `gcc`?

Comment: Is the `Bezeir.h` included in the `Parser.cpp` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link `parser.cpp` with `Bezeir.o`, so to compile you can use something like:

```
g++ parser.cpp Bezeir.cpp
```

Also note that the correct spelling is `Bezier`, not `Bezeir`.

Comment: @user3522932: "That worked, thanks" is normally expressed (around here) by clicking on the grey triangle above the big number at the left side and/or the check-mark you see just below the number and triangles (those "up-vote" and "accept" the answer, respectively).

Comment: Alas, it wouldn't let me. Since I'm new it said I needed more points to vote. :(

Comment: Answer a few questions (or just ask more as good as this one) and you'll get more privileges.